# How do I refer to "this" inside filter function of querySelectorAll?

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-scraping, puppeteer, cheerio

I have Cheerio code that looks like this:

```
const title = $("meta")
            .filter(function () {
              return (
                ($(this).attr("property") != null &&
                  $(this).attr("property").endsWith("title")) ||
              );
            }).attr("content")
```

I want to migrate this to puppeteer, which uses client-side javascript. I have this so far:

```
const title = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("meta")
            .filter(function () {
              return {
              // stuck here: how do I call this?
              // $(this)
```

I am stuck on how to refer to "this" using document query selector syntax.

Comment: Note that the code in the question can be rewritten entirely as `const elem = document.querySelector("meta[property$='title']); const title = elem && elem.getAttribute("content");` Similarily, the one in your answer is just `document.queySelectorAll("meta[name$='title']")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the first parameter of `Array.prototype.filter`, which refers to the current element being iterated over.

Or, since it looks like you just want the *first* match, use `.find` instead:

```
const title = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("meta"))
  .find(function (meta) {
    return String(meta.getAttribute('property')).endsWith("title");
  })
  .getAttribute('content');
```

You can do the same sort of thing in Cheerio as well, except that the element being iterated over is *both* put into `this` *and* into the second parameter.

```
const title = $("meta")
.filter(function (_, meta) {
  return (
    ($(meta).attr("property") != null &&
     $(meta).attr("property").endsWith("title"))
  );
}).attr("content")
```

(but `this` is generally used with cheerio and jQuery)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! You just have to put in an argument into the callback. Should have known that.

Ex:

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("meta")
            .filter(function (el) {
              return el.name !== null && el.name.endsWith("title")
```